# How to SELECT based on another SELECT with multiple rows as response?

Tags: sql, sql-server

*NB: Not being a savvy SQL coder I admit that my googling prior to asking might be flawed. Please have patience if I missed something obvious to others.*

I have a *select* statement, which gives a single row or a multiple rows as a reply. Then, I'm executing a different *select* statement with a parameter that is fetched from the first row. Then, I execute the very same *select* statement again but with the parameter fetched from the second row and so on.

I'd like to put that into a single statement in SQL but, regrettably enough, I lack the skils for that. How do I do that?

At the moment, I'm fetching the first set of data separately. Then, I do some C# magic and execute each of the following, parametrized, statements individually. Waaay not neat...

The issue can be restated as follows. Of course, that's not how I'll solve it in the end (there'll be an SP doing that) but it shows the approach we use today, which we're very discomforted about.

```csharp
String mainCommand = "select Index from SomeTable";
...
foreach(String parameter in ...)
{
  String subCommand = 
    "select RealValue from AnotherTable where Index = " + parameter;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say

```
table1 = {Id1, name, etc...}
table2 = {Id2, name, Id1, etc...}
```

What I understand you want is to, for example, do a select from table 1 to get some rows, and then do a different select with an item from those rows in table 2.
That can be achieved with:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 
 WHERE ID1 IN (SELECT ID1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE="WhatEver condition you are looking for")
```

This performs a select in Table 2 where the column Id1 is in a list from the second select (which only brings a list of Id's from Table1 that fulfill a condition)

Answer (score 5):

You want to use a join operation and a subquery to perform your operation all at the same time.

Something like this:

```
 SELECT [fields] from tbl_mainCommand
 JOIN 
 (SELECT [fields] from tbl_subCommand) 
     on tbl_mainCommand.fieldKey = tbl_subCommand.fieldKey
```

Depending on how your tables are set up, the subquery may not be the most efficient way of doing this as it could result in a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery). But ultimately the nice thing about SQL and Set Theory is that you can perform a massive operation like this all at once as opposed to iterating over a number of parameters and running multiple SQL statements.

Note that the `on tbl...` line is your link between the tables. This is essentially where you are passing your parameter into your second table or subquery. If you can look at it more as a link between two different data sets as opposed to passing a parameter, you are more likely to avoid the correlated subquery.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest to do it with CTE like:

```
With IndexSet AS 
(Select index from SomeTable)
Select RealValue from AnotherTable INNER JOIN 
                      IndexSet ON AnotherTable.INdex=INdexSet.Index
```

Comment: Is this SQL á la Microsoft? I'm working SQL Server here so I'm not able to do the magic available to Oraclees and Mysqlers.  :)

Comment: Yes, this is SQL Server (2005+)